# FreePBX showing only Welcome Page. Internal Pages are not working

Tags: php, apache, asterisk, httpd.conf, freepbx

I have FreePBX setup on CentOS, I was trying to install PHPMyAdmin. But after installation it changed some Apache/httpd configurations which conflicted with the FreePBX configurations. Now FreePBX showing only Welcome Page. I am able to login to Admin Dashboard but when I'm trying to open any other internal pages it returns to Welcome screen and no other URL's are working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. Problem with the file permissions for session files. Internal pages redirects to Welcome page due to fail in writing Session Data in Files. Found that with the help of httpd error log.